# Is it possible to set localStorage in Firefox/Chrome/Safari from the command line?

Tags: safari, google-chrome, iterm, firefox

Trying to automate some tasks I do multiple times every day, such as opening my browser and setting localStorage to the values I need. So far I'm able to open the browser on a site from the command line with

```
open -a {BROWSER} -g http://localhost:3000
```

what would then be great was if I could set localStorage values to this url, such as

```
open -a {BROWSER} -g http://localhost:3000 setLocalStorage('bla', 'bla')
```

Is this possible or is there something close?